# Update MySQL Database with information from drag-and-drop event

Tags: php, mysql, charisma

I am using [this template](http://usman.it/free-responsive-admin-template/) to build a website for a church.

The church wants a really good calendar entry point to add events.

With the calendar on the current template it's nice and simple and you can drag the events onto the corresponding date. What I need is a way to get the date where the event has been dragged onto so I can update the MySQL database.

Here is the link to the direct calendar http://usman.it/themes/charisma/calendar.html

The code for showing the calendar is just

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: Use ajax. This is help for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the calender is loaded through javascript.

If you take a look at the charisma.js inside the themes folder you should be able to see that the calendar will be invoked for example as follows,

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ << some  options here >> });
```

you can go through the documentation for the full calendar at the following site :

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use datepicker, see:
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

Comment: No - i want to get the details of where the date has been placed - http://usman.it/themes/charisma/calendar.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you're usig draggables (jquery), you can hook into their events to collect the data: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events

check out the api documentation for the possiblities: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/